# 'openface' has no attribute 'AlignDlib'

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, openfaces

I am following (https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78) to make a face recognition. I am on step 2 i.e. finding landmarks and affine transformation. Error message is

```
    align = openface.AlignDlib(args.dlibFacePredictor)
AttributeError: module 'openface' has no attribute 'AlignDlib'
```

Also, share how to find embedding from the face using openface in python3.6
Is this issue because of python3.x?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed as follows:

I was trying to **import openface** and use openface.AlignDlib in my script **python/[step-2b_projecting-faces.py](https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/82d0ea0fdb56dc93cb9b716e7ceb364b?source=post_page---------------------------)**, but the class **AlignDlib** was not in the route of the import, the file that has the class I need is **python/openface/openface/align_dlib.pyalign_dlib.py**. So I fixed with changed the import route like this: **import openface.openface.align_dlib as openface**
And works Good. I hope this works.
Note: My python is: Python 3.6.8.